# How to add horizontal scroll view and a listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to create a application in that i need to create a list view but on the top of that i want a horizontal listview for multiple data .I am confused how can we do this .please help me in this

**MainActivityXML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomePage">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/mydata"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In the `mydata` i want to add the dynamic xml layout that is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="ABC DEF JKL"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in the `main_activity.xml` i want to add a horizontal listview but  i am not able to do this .

**HorizontialListView**

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#fff"
  >

  <com.test.ui.HorizontialListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ddd"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my `horizontalitems`

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to create something like this
[image: I want to create like this]

Issuse i am facing is how could the connect all them .Please guide me in this

Comment: where do you want to add the horizontal ListVIew? below ScrollView?

Comment: @HeisenBerg not below the scrollview i want that on the top of the scrollview

Comment: I think scrollview can contain only one direct child. So create a vertical linear layout inside the scroll view and inside that, create your Horizontal ListView and the other LinearLayout(myData)

Comment: @HeisenBerg how can we do this i need a horizontal scroll on top also

Comment: If your horizontal listview scroll with listview means want to scroll full content then you need to add both of then in ScrollView in which you need to set LinearLayout in which your Horizontal listview and apply weight to linearlayout and same as for listView which is in LinearLayout also and apply weight to it also.

Comment: You can use Parallax ListView also. Check this link http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/

Comment: @PiyushGupta i am not getting u ??

Comment: For my first comment?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), you can have

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

Then in code you can set **horizontal** orientation like this.

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

And you can use [RecyclerView.Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) for adding views to it. All set :)

Answer (score 0):

from the picture you've given, I dont think there's a need for a scrollview, you're looking for something like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.test.ui.HorizontialListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        // add the layout for filter and sort by here

    </LinearLayout> 

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal scroll part, use **LinearLayout** surrounded with **HorizontalScrollView** and then add each inner LinearLayout programmatically.

And for the below part use custom ListView.

I guess that will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will Help You

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

// You can use your own code over here

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```